# How do I use modulo 24-hour format on time greater than 23:59:59

Tags: mysql

When I use `addtime(time1,time2)`, it gives results greater than `23:59:59`.

I just need to use the modulo operator on it.

Example, if result obtained is `25:0:0`, I need to make it `01:00:00`.

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try the following:

```
SELECT SEC_TO_TIME(MOD(TIME_TO_SEC('25:23:00'), 86400));

+--------------------------------------------------+
| SEC_TO_TIME(MOD(TIME_TO_SEC('25:23:00'), 86400)) |
+--------------------------------------------------+
| 01:23:00                                         |
+--------------------------------------------------+
```